# How to get the name form the string[] array comparing to the number given

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Actually i am working on a sample code of my own trail where i enter a mobile number and click on buttonso that a form will open on that form i would like to show the name of that coresponding number from the string[] array available in the form

Assume i have

```
string[] User = { "XYZ", "ABC", "DEF" };
string[] Number = { "1234567890", "2345678901", "345678901" };
```

Assume i enter `1234567890` and click on enter i would like to display the corresponding name from the list avialable i.e `XYZ`.

I don't know whteher i explain my problem clearly or not but it is similar to the finding the contact available.

Any better method please let me know..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<long, string>` is what you need here.

```
Dictionary<long, string> nameFromNumber = new Dictionary<long, string>();

nameFromNumber.Add(1234567890, "XYZ");
nameFromNumber.Add(2345678901, "ABC");
...
```

Then to find the name of the inserted number you can do:

```
long numberToCheck = 12364567890;
if (nameFromNumber.ContainsKey(numberToCheck)//Contains(numberToCheck)
{
    string name = nameFromNumber[numberToCheck];
    ...
}
```

**Edit:** change the signature to long instead of int, thanks to @Kirill how pointed this out, Anyway I personally would use string instead so my method will accept more generic format of numbers such as `012-3456789`

Comment: `2345678901` will throw `OverflowException` :-) Use `uint/long/ulong` instead.

Comment: @Vivekh use `string` here instead so if the number was in other format  like `505-1234-60` you can interact with it, so make the deceleration `Dictionary<string, string>` instead

Comment: I am not having contains as i am unsing 2.0 whats the alternative

Comment: `string name = nameFromNumber[numberToCheck]; ` this is not giving me the name i required

Comment: @Vivekh it is a typo in declaring `numberToCheck = 12364567890` it should be `1234567890` instead of `12364567890`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = 
    Number.Zip(User, (a, b) => new { a, b }).ToDictionary(k => k.a, v => v.b);

Console.WriteLine(result["1234567890"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) to find the index of the item within the first array. Then use that index to locate the corresponding value in the second array.

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(Number, "1234567890");
string name = User[index];
```

However, a structure that maps one value to another would be better here. In C# the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class serves this function, for example:

```
var peeps = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                               { "1234567890", "Bob" }, 
                                               ...
                                           };
var peep = peeps["1234567890"]; // will throw if doesn't exist
```

To handle missing entries:

```
var peep;
if (!peeps.TryGet(number, out peep)) throw new SomeException("Nobody with that number.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
// Assuming you have entered a number in a textbox
string[] User = { "XYZ", "ABC", "DEF" }; 
string[] Number = { "1234567890", "2345678901", "345678901" }; 
foreach(string s in Number)
{
if(s == textBox1.Text)
{
MessageBox.Show(User[s]);
}
}
```